# A timely burnination request

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hour): no wiki, no synonyms, 170 questions. [minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minute): no wiki, no synonyms, 52 questions.

Nearly all questions on these tags are, of course, dealing with [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) in some way or other. Does indicating what exactly is being measured in a certain scenario, hours or minutes, make much sense? I don't think it does.

**UPDATE:**

more of this stuff, thanks to the commenters! [seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seconds), [milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/milliseconds) and [days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/days) (whoa, that one even has a tag wiki!) should probably burn too.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

(again, thanks to the commenters):

[weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weekday), [weekend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weekend) *facepalm*

The number of tags in this issue is growing like a snowball... how very un-time-ly.

Comment: Don't forget on [tag:seconds] and [tag:milliseconds].

Comment: Don't forget [days] either !

Comment: ...and [tag:weekday], and [tag:weekend]...

Comment: Can we just synonymize all of them to [time]?

Comment: @l4mpi: I don't think so. [seconds] `is` [time], but [time] `!is` [seconds]. IIRC, synonyms are two-way, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mints97 what? Of course not. Creating a synonym means any time somebody attempts to tag something with e.g. [seconds] it will get tagged with [time] instead. The reverse of that is of course not true.

Comment: @l4mpi: I see, so synonyms *aren't* two-way! I stand corrected, thanks =)

Comment: @l4mpi "If you know of common, **alternate spellings or phrasings** for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks." I don't believe seconds is an alternative spelling of time: "What second/time it is?" would yield different kind of answers.

Comment: @Braiam of course it's not an alternative spelling, but `python-shell` is not an alternative spelling of `python` either. The same holds true for `jdk` and `jre` which are not alternative spellings of `java`. Fact is, when a user tags a question with [minutes] or [seconds] etc, it would be beneficial to remove that tag and instead add the [time] tag. And while that might not be the intended use of synonyms, they are the only tool we can use for this. The alternative is to completely remove the tags, and see them recretated in at most a week, as blacklisting never happens.

Comment: There's also [tag:workday], which seems to be more or less the same thing as [tag:weekday] (they [aren't synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/workday/synonyms), though).

Comment: Fully agree that those tags should be removed. They add no information, and they're not something one would reasonably want to search for or filter on.

Comment: workday and weekday aren't synonyms @GoBusto - as workdays exclude public holidays.

Comment: Your edit made no sense @Prof - it appeared as though you wanted to remove the tag `[request]`..., which is that the square brackets imply.

Comment: Depending on the language/environment, measuring in fractional seconds can be horrific, equally calenders can cause havoc with workdays etc. Is there any specific reason you think these tags are actively harmful or are you just trying to come up with a pun?

Comment: Some of these tags might be more related to [tag:date] than [tag:time].