# The [hour] has come to burn

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hour) is pretty useless and is just used for people who like to overuse tags about questions. Additionally, there are no usage guidelines for the tag. It is mostly used as an extra tag in questions about time or is just tagged because the word hour is used at some point within the question. There has been a previous request to burninate all of the respective time-subdivision tags in the past (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289771/a-timely-burnination-request)), but there was no resolution and this did not follow the rules of requesting only one tag per burninate request. Of this tag, there has been 1 question in the past 7 days, and 2 in the past 30 days. It would seem a lot more useful to just remove this tag entirely.

Comment: _For whom the bell tolls_ :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's pretty good as well.

Comment: Uh oh... *cometh the final [hour]*

Comment: @JonClements The burninator cometh?

Comment: I *second* this proposal.

Comment: @EliSadoff if you'll just stand right here… *(points to pentagram)*

Comment: How about [minute] and [seconds] too?

Comment: @faintsignal I agree, but burninate requests by rule are only allowed to be for one tag per post.

Comment: @EliSadoff Better get a couple more puns ready

Comment: @faintsignal I'll let some others take care of those. I'm learning that Meta SO is apparently just a place for time puns.

Comment: @yellowantphil I had tagged that in my post as well and explained the difference.

Comment: @yellowantphil No worries!

Comment: @faintsignal burning all three should be a *minute* task

Comment: [hour] problem is all these useless tags.

Comment: If there was a [days] tag... "End of [days]"

Comment: Seeing meta burn requests in the most cringe-worthy part of my day.

Comment: Expanding on @JonClements' answer and if `<strike>` worked in titles; _Cometh the [hour], cometh the <strike>man</strike> Burninator_

Comment: @paulvs I am yet to see a "funny" title that makes me smile, let alone laugh.

Comment: Why did this get marked as a duplicate? I feel like I adequately explained and addressed the differences between this and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289771/a-timely-burnination-request.